# PowerShell Azure Cmdlet not Recognized

Tags: powershell, azure

Running PowerShell ISE (V4), I install the AzureRM module as follows

```
Import-Module AzureRM
```

I then check the version

```
(get-module azurerm).Version
```

which returns

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
3      4      0      -1
```

I then attempt to use the login cmdlet

```
Login-AzureRmAccount
```

but get the error

```
Login-AzureRmAccount : The term 'Login-AzureRmAccount' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the 
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Login-AzureRmAccount
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Login-AzureRmAccount:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

What am I doing wrong?

**NOTE**
I'm working behind a proxy and have used the following command to get round it

```
[System.Net.WebRequest]::DefaultWebProxy.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultCredentials
```

I've also set the PSGallery repo as follows

```
Register-PSRepository -Name "PSGallery" -SourceLocation "https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/" -InstallationPolicy Trusted
```

Comment: try reinstalling the whole module?

Comment: Now when attempting `Install-Module AzureRm` I get the error `No match was found for the specified search criteria and module name AzureRm`. Similar to [this](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/1874). Will try installing `PowerShellGet` again.

Comment: Nope. Windows 8.1. I am working behind a proxy - not sure if this is causing the error in my previous comment. Weird though coz I can list all the Azure modules, just can't seem to use them.

Comment: What do you get from this: Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name Azure -Refresh

Comment: @juvchan: Nothing shown when I use that command. But I do get quite a long list if I use `Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name Azure* -Refresh`. Do I need to `Install-Module Azure` as well as `Install-Module AzureRM`? I thought former was just for ASM.

Comment: What do u get from: Get-Module -Name AzureRm.Profile

Comment: This is doing m head in. Why is it so difficult?? Re-installed `Azure` and `AzureRM` modules. Can see all the modules with `Get-Module` cmdlet, but just can't use them. C'mon MS....

Comment: @juvchan I get the following `Script 2.5.0 AzureRM.Profile {Add-AzureRmAccount, Add-AzureRmEnvironment, ...`

Answer (score 2):

> I upgraded to Windows Management Framework 5 and I can now run the
>   command Login-AzureRMAccount

Also we can download the Azure PowerShell installation file and install it.
We can download the PS version 3.3.0 installation file from this page:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/releases/tag/v3.3.0-December2016

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Login-AzureRmAccount is simply an alias for Add-AzureRmAccount which is used to access the ARM resources in your Azure account.

Add-AzureAccount is used to access the "classic" resources in your Azure account.

Comment: So `Add-AzureAccount` appears to work - window opens for me to add credentials etc. Running `Get-AzureAccount` shows me my account. However, trying to use a command like `New-AzureRmResourceGroup ...` just errors telling me to `Run Login-AzureRmAccount` - when I try and do that I get the same error as before, i.e., `.. is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet...`.

Comment: Are you able to run `Add-AzureRmAccount`? You cannot run `New-AzureRmResoucegroup` because you are only logged in to access classic resources (`Add-AzureAccount`).

Comment: Makes sense, but still stuck with my quandry - can't use `Login-AzureRmAccount` as it's not recognised, apparently.

Comment: Did you run both `Install-Module AzureRM` and `Install-AzureRm`?

Comment: I've run `Install-Module AzureRM` and `Import-Module AzureRM` - what's `Install-AzureRM`?

Comment: The first command installs the AzureRM module from the PowerShell Gallery. The second command installs all the component modules of Azure Resource Manager in the module version range specified in the AzureRM module. Link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/resourcemanager/

Comment: So your link helped. I upgraded to *Windows Management Framework 5* and I can now run the command `Login-AzureRMAccount`. However, `Install-AzureRM` isn't recognised as a cmdlet, but that doesn't appear to be stopping progress yet.

Comment: @JamesB you had upgraded to windows management framework 5, you can download the azure powershell installation file and install it. https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/releases/tag/v3.3.0-December2016